# Creating Floating Div Elements in Phonegap

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, css-float

Does somebody have a solution for floating elements in Phonegap with JQuery Mobile?
In my browser in works so far, but when I start the app on my phone, the elements are displayed vertically.
My Code:

```
<div class="category-item">
    <img alt="Cocktails" src="../img/cocktails.png"><br> 
    <span>Cocktails</span>
</div>
```

and in my *.css

```
.category-item{
width: 120px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Screen width matters for floating elements.

Comment: what phone/os are you targeting?

Comment: I use Phonegap for Android 2.3. For debugging i use my Samsung Galaxy S Plus

Comment: I found the solution after 2 hours !! A link to the css file has to be added in the index.html